How to unscrew a screw that has no longer a position for the screwdriver head?
I tried to open a small device to replace the battery but none of my screwdrivers matched. In the end the screw itself started to lose form and became round so I don't know what to use to unscrew it.
Is there a way to unscrew it now that the slots that you put in a screwdriver have been "molded" away and is a big hole in the center? See image


I have always had good luck taking my rotary tool with a cutoff disk and cutting a new slot into the screw and using a slotted screwdriver to remove the screw. The new slot might have to extend into the plastic depending on the size of the cutoff disk but that should not affect anything but the appearance.

Seeing it is plastic, epoxy(maybe with weld in the name) something just on the head might work.
You have to be careful to not epoxy it to the plastic, maybe use some paper or tape to make a small tube around the head, for protection.
Use or buy the proper fitting driver next time.
If the epoxy does not work, you are probably looking at drilling the head off, or enough to use a screw extractor.

What do you mean with epoxy?

By the way or buy the proper fitting driver next time. I have a set of mini screwdrivers. I don't understand why they sell devices that expect you to unscrew it to replace the battery and to do that one has to have a super special screwdriver.

Epoxy adhesive, sometimes in two parts, one has weld after two initials in its name.  For strength.  Super/crazy/instant glue might work, but I think an epoxy type will be stronger to hold long enough to remove that screw.

Talk to the designers.  I have a piece of machinery that has one nut that needs a grinder or touch to it cut off.  It is usually rusted after years when it needs removing.

Battery compartments are often secured with screws to prevent kids playing or eating batteries. So safety considerations top your convenience.
